# Guide to install SharePoint updates via Configuration Manager (SCCM)?

Tags: 2013, 2010, 2016

Over the last decade, there has been mixed guidance on installing SharePoint updates via WSUS/SCCM. I am not talking about the PSConfig/PSConfigUI here. I am referring to the Cumulative Updates, Service Packs, Uber packages, etc.

Does anyone have a guide / references on packaging SharePoint updates via Configuration Manager (SCCM) - 
now Microsoft Endpoint Configuration Manager?

Thanks!